# Changing array inside function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am learning C and confused why a array created in the main wont change inside the function, i am assuming the array passed is a pointer, and changing the pointer should've change the array , right ? can someone explain what is happening in this case?

thx for the help.

```c
int main(){
    int i, length = 10;
    int array[length];

    for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        array[i] = i * 10;
    printf("Before:");
    print(array, length);
    change(array, length);
    printf("After:");
    print(array, length);

    return 0;
}

// Print on console the array of int
void print(int *array,int length)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

// Change the pointer of the array
void change(int *array,int length)
{
    int *new = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        new[i] = 1;
    array = new;
}
```

I expected to see the following output:

```
Before:0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
After:1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

What i get:

```
Before:0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
After:0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Comment: Never, not even for test.

Comment: can u give any tips then? thx

Comment: Array is a local variable inside both `main` and `change`.  Its address is passed from `main` to `change`.  After that, `change` can reassign it and it will have no effect on the array in `main`.  The two variables are unrelated.  Now, `change` may change the *contents* of `array`, in which case `main` will see the change as well.

Comment: Just see my answer, and you might understand what I mean. For compilers `for(int i=0;i<length;i++)` is perfectly readable but for humans ... It's better as `for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)`. Also, writing multiple statements in the same line makes it even harder to read.

Comment: Don't use malloc for such a task. [Try this](http://ideone.com/z382j0).

Comment: Is a good habit to use "const" whenever you want a function not to modify something. Hence, just to make sure you are actually printing and not trying to modify the array inside the print function you should change your print function to void print(const int *array, int length){..}.

Comment: I'm confused why `void f(int i) {i = 5;} int main() {int x = 0; f(x); printf("%d\n", x); return 0;}` doesn't print 5? Didn't I change x inside the function?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) you can't pass a variable by reference, the `array` variable that you assign inside the function contains initially the same address as the passed pointer, but it's a copy of it so modifying it will not alter the passed pointer.

You need to pass the address of the pointer in order to be able to alter it, like this

```
// Change the pointer of the array
void change(int **array, int length)
{
    *array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (*array == NULL)
        return;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        (*array)[i] = 1;
}
```

Then in `main()` you cannot assign to an array, doing so through this kind of function is surely undefined behavior. The array defined in `main()` is allocated on the stack and you cannot assign anything to an array since they are *non*-writeable *lvalues* so you cannot make it point to a heap memory location obtained with `malloc()`, you need to pass a pointer like this

```
int *array;
change(&array, length);
free(array);
```

If you want the function to replace the previous array, it will have to `free()` the `malloc()`ed data (*note that passing `NULL` to `free()` is well defined*), so

```
// Change the pointer of the array
void change(int **array, int length)
{
    free(*array);

    *array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (*array == NULL)
        return;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
        (*array)[i] = 1;
}
```

then in `main()`

```
int *array;
array = NULL;
change(&array, length);
change(&array, length);
change(&array, length);
change(&array, length);
free(array);
```

will do what you apparently want.

Comment: They both look the same except `free()`.  I just want to change one element in the array so which one do I use?

Comment: But if I change directly the `arr` created in `main()`, I don't need to do any of this as changes are applied to the `arr` in `main()`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i will make the answer short.

1. Arrays are always passed by reference in C

change(array, length);
  In this line, it means reference to the first element of the array variable is passed to the function.

Now the function needs a pointer to catch the reference, it can be a pointer or it can be an array. Note that the pointer or the array is local to the function.

2. You received it in a pointer named array. Which is definitely a pointer but it is not the same as array in main function. It is local to the change function.
3. You declared a new array dynamically, and assigned a pointer named new with it. And all the changes you did were to new pointer.

Everything is ok till now.

4. Now you assigned the new pointer to the array pointer which is local to the change function.

This is the real issue. As even though the array is in heap section, and it will remain in the memory, but the *array and *new are local pointer variables.

Also array pointer in change function is different from array pointer in main function.

5. The solution to this problem is
   Manipulate the data of array pointer directly.

   void change(int *array,int length)
   {
       int i;
       for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
           array[i] = 1;
   }

In this way you are directly overwriting values of array in main function. Everything else is correct.

Summerization: 
array pointer in change function is local to change function. 
array in main function is local to main function. 
Making change function's local array pointer point to array in heap section won't change data in actual array. You changed pointer's position, Not the array's data.

Answer (score 1):

Your array in main is an *array*. It will decay to a pointer, to produce the behavior you expect, but it is *not* a pointer.

```
int a[10];
int* p = a; // equivalent to &a[0]; create a pointer to the first element
a = p;      // illegal, a is NOT a pointer.
```

What your code is doing is copying the address of a into a function-local variable. Modifying it will have no more difference outside than changing length.

```
void change(int* local_ptr, size_t length)
{
    local_ptr = 0;
    length = 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int length = 10;
    printf("before a=%p, length=%d\n", a, length);
    change(a, length);  // we copied 'a' into 'local_ptr'. 
    printf("after a=%p, length=%d\n", a, length);
}
```

If you wish to modify a pointer from the caller, you will need to use pointer-to-pointer syntax:

```
void change(int** ptr, size_t length)
{
    // change the first element:
    **ptr = 0;
    // change the pointer:
    *ptr = 0;
    // but ptr itself is a function-local variable
    ptr = 0;  // local effect
}
```

However: There is a problem with what you are trying to do that goes deeper than this.

In your code, "int a" is an array on the stack, not an allocated pointer; you cannot free it and you should avoid mixing heap/stack pointers this way because eventually you'll free the wrong thing.

Comment: So changing the second element is `**ptr[1]=0`?

Answer (score 1):

### A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(const int arr[], const int n){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void change_array(int arr[]){
    arr[0] = 239;
    arr[1] = 234234;
}

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {};
    print_array(arr,10);
    change_array(arr);
    print_array(arr,10);
    return 0;
}
```

###### The output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
239 234234 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the simplest way to modify the data pointed to by 'array', rewrite the 'change' function to:

```
// [OLD COMMENT] Change the pointer of the array
// [NEW COMMENT] Change the value(s) of data pointed to by 'array'
void change(int *array, int length)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
       array[i] = 1;
}
```

When you pass the name of the integer array called 'array', you are passing a pointer to the array data declared in main. In the function 'change' the pointer is copied (passed by value) and it is used in the function as it would have in main. No need for malloc.

Answer (score 0):

You pass a pointer to the array `array` to the function `change`. In this function you create another array called `new` (using `new` as a name is a bad idea) and then assign it to the **locally created function parameter `array`**. You **do not** modify pointer in your `main` function. If you would like to do so, you should use

```
array = change(array,length);
```

in your main function and

```
int *change(int *array, int length) {
    int *variable_called_new =(int *)malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    [...]
    return variable_called_new
}
```

in your `change` function.

Comment: thx it worked ,but there is anyway to change the pointer of the array without returning a int pointer ?

Comment: @VictorFerreira: You can find this in iharob answer. Just pass a pointer to a pointer to an array :)

Answer (score 0):

*To use pass by value*:
Make the following change:
In function `change(...)`, replace:

```
int i;for(i=0;i<length;i++)new[i] = 1;
```

To:

```
int i;for(i=0;i<length;i++)array[i] = 1;
                           ^^^^^
```

*EDIT*:
*But to use pass by reference*:

```
//To change the contents of a variable via a function call
//the address of that variable has to be passed. So, if you
//want to change the contents of an array of int, i.e. int *array, you 
//need to pass its address, not the variable itself,  using the 
//address of operator, it would look like this &array (read _the address of
// pointer to int "array")
//This requires you to change the prototype of your function:
void change2(int **a, int len)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) (*a)[i] = 1;//parenthesis bind * to a to assure 
                                   //array of pointers to int ( *[] )is populated
                                   //
}
```

Then in main, make the following changes, and it will work as you purposed:

```
int main(){
    int i,length=10;
    int *array;

    array = calloc(length, sizeof(int));
    if(!array) return 0;
    //or malloc if preferred.  But note, in C, 
    //casting the output is not required on either.
    //array = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    //if(!array) return 0;

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)array[i]=i*10;

    printf("Before:");print(array,length);
    change2(&array,length);
    printf("After:");print(array,length);

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i wanna change the pointer , not value by value ,but thx anyway

Comment: @VictorFerreira , then you have to pass the pointer to be changed, not the value.  See my edit in a few minutes.

Comment: Victor, what do you mean when you say "you want to change the pointer"? You did change the pointer. By the way, things might be less confusing if you used a different name (other than "array" for the pointer passed to "change"), so when you say you want to change "X" it will be clear what you mean.

Comment: @Stuart - I think you have to use "@Victor Ferreira" in the comment, and it will flag Victor...

Comment: @ryyker Thanks, I wasn't trying to flag him, I figured he was waiting for your comment, so I didn't want to push in front of you. By the way, if you going to tell him to pass a pointer to a pointer then it won't work. At least not in the sense of changing "array" in the main function (which is impossible).

Answer (score 0):

so when you pass the array you get the address of it's beginning:

*memory* *address*

|-junk-|  1000

|---0---|  1008  <- start of your array

|---10--|  1012

.       .
  .       .

when you get the pointer in your function its value is 1008(example) so changing that will only mean you now point to another place. that is not what you want. 
you can change the integers pointed at directly via the * operator, so 
`*array = 99;` will change the first element,
`*(array+1) = 98;` the second and so on.
you can also, more naturally use the [] operator.
so in your function
 `array[0] = 99;` will actually change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>

            // Print on console the array of int
            void print(int *array,int length)
            {
                int i;
                for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
                    printf("%d ", array[i]);
                printf("\n");
            }

            // Change the pointer of the array
            void change(int **array,int length)
            {
                int i;
                int *ar;
                ar = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *) * length);
                for(i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
                    ar[i] = 1;
                (*array) = ar;
            }

            int main(){
                int i, length = 10;
                int *array;
                array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int *) * length);

                for (i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
                    array[i] = i * 10;
                printf("Before:");
                print(array, length);
                change(&array, length);
                printf("After:");
                print(array, length);

                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what is different in your solution than in the original question, and why it solves the problem? Also, both the original code and your code have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your array's reference to the function `change()` and the rererence is getting copied to pointer array in change.

And then you're creating a variable `new` and assigning the memory space using `malloc` and following that you're assigning some values to it.

Until now your pointer array in `change()` is pointing to the array in main.

In the next statement you're making your array in `change()` point to the space pointed by the  variable `new and the pointar array is not pointing to the array in the main any more.

So instead of using `new[i] = 1` use `array[i] = 1` in `change()`.