# Changing elements of an array by passing by reference to a function

Tags: c, arrays, element, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass an array by reference and change the values in the array in changeArray(). I am getting an error which states "Access violation writing location 0x00000001." I read [Changing array inside function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844003/changing-array-inside-function-in-c) and I used Ryyker's answer to achieve my intended result (to have x[]={1,1,1,1,1]) but I get the aforementioned error. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int changeArray(int **a);

int main(void) {

    int *x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };
    int *y[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };

    changeArray(&x);
    for (int z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
        printf_s("%s", x[z]);
    }
    free(x);
}

int changeArray(int **a) {

    for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) {
        (*a)[z] = 1;
    }
}
```

I know there are similar posts, but all the ones I have seen don't seem to solve my problem, any help is appreciated!

Comment: `int *x[5]` should be `int x[5]` (the same for `y`) and `int changeArray(int **a)` should be `int changeArray(int (*a)[5])`.

Comment: Remove the * before x and y. Also, you shouldn't call `free(x)`, as the array is not heap allocated

Comment: With this statement you are filling address 1,5,4,3,1 in pointer x[0], x[1] ... int *x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 }; It is similar like int *x = 5; which is not valid better take integer type array it does not mandatory variable to be of pointer type for call by reference.

Comment: How did you **not** get any compiler diagnostics? There are *none* mentioned in your post. Please find out where the compiler outputs the diagnostics messages!

Comment: `"Access violation writing location 0x00000001."` **Ouch!**. You are trying to access memory at Address `1` which is at the very bottom of the *System Reserved* memory pool. Not good.

Answer (score 3):

Your program is doing something completely unintended.

```
int *x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };
int *y[5]= { 1,5,4,3,1 };
```

Here you're initializing a bunch of int *pointers* with values from 1 to 5. So they point to invalid memory.

Then later, here:

```
for (int z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
    printf_s("%s", x[z]);
}
```

You are telling it to print the string at that invalid memory.

The `0x00000001` in `Access violation writing location 0x00000001` is actually the hex representation of the first `1` in `int *x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };`.

What you probably want is this:

```
int changeArray(int *a) {

    for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) {
        a[z] = 1;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
int main(void) {

    int x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };

    changeArray(x);
    for (int z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
        printf("%d", x[z]); // also consider adding space, such as "%d "
    }
}
```

Comment: Well done, there was no need to pass a pointer to array to begin with since the array had automatic storage type with its scope in `main()` to begin with...

Comment: Yeah, I think OP misundestood how pointers and arrays work in C. I can relate, it took me a good while to understand those properly.

Comment: We all have that same bump on our foreheads from beating our head into that same wall when we were learning `:)`

Answer (score 1):

- `int *x[5]` should be `int x[5]`.
- You do not need `int y[5]` at all.
- `int changeArray(int **a)` should be `void changeArray(int (*a)[5])`.
- You pass a pointer to an array and return nothing. `free(x);` is
  wrong, `x` is on the stack and must not be freed.
- `printf_s("%s", x[z]);` should be `printf("%d ", x[z]);`, `x[z]` is an `int` and so it needs `%d` as format specifier. Also note the space after it to see the different numbers and not only a large number.

Here is your corrected code https://ideone.com/kwXrFg

Comment: Nice answer mch, but it's not like `x` doesn't need to be freed, it must not be freed, as I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeArray(int (*a)[5]);

int main(void) {
    int x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };
    changeArray(&x);
    for (int z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
        printf_s("%d", x[z]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void changeArray(int (*a)[5]) {
    for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) {
        (*a)[z] = 1;
    }
}
```

and give output:

> 11111

as you can see in the <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MBnhI7qqUPDtWAoB)</kbd>.

---

Here are the changes I made:

- Change `int *x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };` to `int x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };`.
- Remove `y`, since you do not use it.
- Change the prototype of your function to: `void changeArray(int
  (*a)[5]);`, since you don't return anything, and the parameter is
  also changed, to pass array `x` as is with the changes now.
- Use `%d` to print integers, not `%s`.
- Remove `free(x)`, since you don't dynamic allocate memory for array
  `x`, thus you must not de-allocate it manually.

Comment: Thanks gsamaras this is interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int changeArray(int *a);

int main(void) {

    int x[5] = { 1,5,4,3,1 };
    int y[5]= { 1,5,4,3,1 };

    changeArray(x);
    for (int z = 0; z <= 4; ++z) {
        printf_s("%s", x[z]);
    }
}

int changeArray(int *a) {

    for (int z = 0; z < 5; ++z) {
        a[z] = 1;
    }
}
```