# Declare a Character array Arr of size5

Tags: solver

Declare a Character array Arr of size 5. Read characters in to it without scanf. Using a pointer variable, change the characters in the Array .
Print the original Arr and then the changed array with Address.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *charArr[5]; // Declare a Character Array of Size 5 (1)
fgets(charArr, 5, stdin); // Read characters into array without scanf (2)

void change(int **array, int length){
    *array = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (*array == NULL)
      return;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++)
       (*array)[i] = 1;
    }
}
printf("%s\n", charArr); // simply prints array of chars (3.a) Inital array set of vals
change(&charArr, 5); // change values within array
printf("%s\n", charArr); // simply prints array of chars (3.b) array set of vals after change

free(array); // Free's up Malloc
```

I'm not to familiar with C but, I think it's something along those lines. I manged to extrapolate a solution using the resources below

**NOTE** if this does fail, please review the stackoverflow link below. It goes into describing that using malloc with predefined memory will likely throw an exception.

Resources:

- [Changing array inside function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844003/changing-array-inside-function-in-c#34844026)
- https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-get-the-integers-in-C-without-using-scanf?share=1