# C change pointer address of array in other function to change the position of values in the array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

```
 typedef struct {
   char* value;
   char* type;
 } CARD;

 CARD cards[52];

 void initializeCards() { 

   char* types[10] = {"Spade", "Club", "Hearts", "Diamonds"};
   char* values[13] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "B", "D", "K"};

   shuffleArray(&values, 4); //I've also tried *values, or just values

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     for (int e = 0; e < 13; e++) {
       cards[i*13 + e].type = types[i];
       cards[i*13 + e].value = values[e];
     }
   }
 }//initializeCards.


 //Code in this function comes from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844003/changing-array-inside-function-in-c
 //I've tried many different things inside this function, none of these seem to work.
 
 void shuffleArray(char** array, uint8_t size) {

    free(*array);

    *array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    //char* temp = (*array)[0];
    //(*array)[0] = 1;

    (*array)[0] = "test";

    printf("%s\n", &array[0]);
 }//shuffleArray.
```

I'm trying to get a deck of cards into an array, these cards should be shuffled, but instead of shuffling the array with the cards, I want to shuffle these 2 shorter arrays 'values' and 'types', because they are shorter and thus take fewer iterations to shuffle.

I've tried many different things none of them worked, What I wanted is to change the pointers of the array
in the function 'shuffleArray' so that the array in the other function automatically changes as well.

if any of you could help me do the following correctly, I think I'll manage in shuffling them completely:

```
//This is pseudo-code, if I get this correctly I should be able to shuffle them.
temp = array[0]
array[0] = array[size-1]
array[size-1] = temp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but you certainly cannot `free` an array that is not allocated via malloc (and family).  Perhaps you want something like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>                                                                  
#include <assert.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
struct card {                                                                      
        char *value;                                                               
        char *suit;                                                                
};                                                                                 
                                                                                   
struct card cards[52];                                                             
                                                                                   
void initializeCards(void);                                                        
void shuffleArray(char **, size_t);                                                
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(void)                                                                         
{                                                                                  
        srand(time(NULL));                                                         
        initializeCards();                                                         
        for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ ){                                             
                printf("%s of %s\n", cards[i].value, cards[i].suit);               
        }                                                                          
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void                                                                               
initializeCards(void)                                                              
{                                                                                  
        char *suits[] = { "Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds" };               
        char *values[] = {                                                         
                "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",                               
                "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"                            
        };                                                                         
                                                                                   
        shuffleArray(values, sizeof values / sizeof *values);                      
        shuffleArray(suits, sizeof suits / sizeof *suits);                         
        struct card *c = cards;                                                    
                                                                                   
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof suits / sizeof *suits; i++ ){               
                for( unsigned e = 0; e < sizeof values / sizeof *values; e++ ){    
                        assert( c < cards + sizeof cards / sizeof *cards );        
                        c->suit = suits[i];                                        
                        c->value = values[e];                                      
                        c += 1;                                                    
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
}                                                                                  
  
void                                                                               
shuffleArray(char **array, size_t n)                                               
{                                                                                  
        for( unsigned i = 0; i < n - 1; i++ ){                                    
                unsigned j = i + rand() % (n - i);                                 
                char *t = array[i];                                                
                array[i] = array[j];;                                              
                array[j] = t;                                                      
        }                                                                          
}
```

Comment: For the length expression, would it be more clear to use   like this "sizeof values / sizeof values[0]"